# visual basic result not showing up in label Error BC42353

Tags: c#, vb.net

So the error is BC42353 ( Function `ValidateInputFields` doesn't return a value on all code paths. Are you missing a `Return` statement? ) I'm getting this error twice. I put exclamation points on the lines that it says the errors are on.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private decWholesaleCost As Decimal
    Private decMarkuppercent As Decimal


    Private Function ValidateInputFields() As Boolean
        If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtWholesale.Text, decWholesaleCost) Then
            lblMessage.Text = "The wholesale cost must be numeric"
            Return False
        End If

        If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtMarkup.Text, decMarkuppercent) Then
            lblMessage.Text = "Markup percentage must be numeric"
            Return False
        End If
!    End Function

    Function CalculateRetailPrice(ByVal decWholesaleCost As Decimal,
                             ByVal decMarkupPercent As Decimal) As Decimal
        Dim decRetailPrice As Decimal
        decRetailPrice = decWholesaleCost + (decWholesaleCost * decMarkupPercent)
!        End Function

    Private Sub BtnGetRetail_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetRetail.Click
        Dim decRetailPrice As Decimal
        lblMessage.Text = String.Empty

        If ValidateInputFields() Then
            decRetailPrice = CalculateRetailPrice(decRetailPrice, decMarkuppercent)
           lblRetail.Text = decRetailPrice.ToString("c")

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't returning any value.

```
Private Function ValidateInputFields() As Boolean
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtWholesale.Text, decWholesaleCost) Then
        lblMessage.Text = "The wholesale cost must be numeric"
        Return False
    End If

    If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtMarkup.Text, decMarkuppercent) Then
        lblMessage.Text = "Markup percentage must be numeric"
        Return False
    End If
  Return True '--need to add this line
End Function
```

If you write a method in .NET that isn't of type void, you have to return a value. Your code doesn't return a value, that's why the compiler is yielding an error.

```
Private Function ValidateInputFields() As Boolean
        If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtWholesale.Text, decWholesaleCost) Then
            lblMessage.Text = "The wholesale cost must be numeric"
            Return False
        End If

        If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtMarkup.Text, decMarkuppercent) Then
            lblMessage.Text = "Markup percentage must be numeric"
            Return False
        End If
     --there is no return value from function when above if condition fails
    End Function
```

Please add `Return True` at the end of your method; that should resolve your issue.

Comment: Likewise, your second function must return a value. Add a line Return decRetailPrice

Comment: I suspect that the default return value should be `True` because the code shows returning `False` when there is a problem.